# Laravel eloquent calculate work experience

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have custom table with users work experiences:

```
Schema::create('workplaces', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('company')->nullable();
    $table->string('position')->nullable();
    $table->string('description')->nullable();
    $table->smallInteger('from')->nullable();
    $table->smallInteger('to')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Here example user experiences data:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| user_id | company | position | description | from | to |
----------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------
|    1    | Google  | Designer | Lorem ipsum | 2018 |null|
----------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |  Yahoo  | Designer | Lorem ipsum | 2014 |2017|
----------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |Microsoft| Designer | Lorem ipsum | 2004 |2008|
----------------------------------------------------------
```

In this example user with `id == 1` has **7 years** work experience.

```
2018 - (2017 - 2014) - (2008 - 2004) = 2011
```

User last year work in 2018 and now I need to subtraction result from last working year:

```
2018 - 2011 = 7
```

Now, current user has 7 year work experience.

How I can calculate custom work experiences using laravel eloquent?

Comment: What do you want to have in output? can you explain that please?

Comment: @HamidNaghipour I need calculate user work experiences. In my example data user has 7 year work experience. How I can calculate it with eloquent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Create a model in `app` folder where filename is `Workplace.php` with following content:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Workplace extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'workplaces';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'company', 'position', 'description', 'from', 'to'];

    public $timestamps = true;


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function experienceYears() 
    {
      $from = property_exists($this, 'from') ? $this->from : null;
      $to = property_exists($this, 'to') ? $this->to : null;
      if (is_null($from)) return 0;
      if (is_null($to)) $to = $from; // or = date('Y'); depending business logic
      return (int)$to - (int)$from;
    }

    public static function calcExperienceYearsForUser(User $user) 
    {
        $workplaces = 
            self::with('experienceYears')
                  ->whereUserId($user->id)
                  ->get(['from', 'to']);
        $years = 0;
        foreach ($workplaces AS $workplace) {
          $years+= $workplace->experienceYears;
        }
        return $years;
    }
}
```

2) Use it in controller's action:

```
$userId = 1;
$User = User::findOrFail($userId);
$yearsOfExperience = Workplace::calcExperienceYearsForUser($User);
```

Comment: How do you think how can I get users with more or less **n**  - years experience?

Comment: @AndreasHunter for such case You've to add `experience_years` field to `users` table and make console command that will run periodically and do calculation and update that field.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should do such calculations on the DB side. It will be a much faster and more flexible solution. What if you got 1 million users with multiple experience entries and want to select top 10 most experienced users? Doing such calculation on the PHP side will be extremely inefficient.

Here's a raw query (Postgres) that might do the main part of the job:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(to_year, extract(year from current_date)) - from_year) from experiences;
```

If you want to play around with it and test other cases: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9840b/3

Others might say that this is a premature optimization, but it's a one liner. Raw queries are very capable and should be employed more often.

Comment: that's perfect solution, but question is: How I can calculate custom work experiences using **laravel eloquent**? I hope there is no such requirement to show top 10 users (:   which will lead to add `experience_years` to `users` table and background worker or database trigger that will calculate numbers and update that field

Comment: Well, I just wanted to provide an idea. One can always "hide" raw query bits within Model class to feel it more eloquent-like. As your answer is technically correct, I think there's no need to elaborate on an alternative. And I agree on the summary table / triggers part.

Comment: what about doing extra addition to Your answer? Cause Andreas wants that feature now (: